# How to load localization storyboard string in ios with programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslocalizedstring

I am gonna to load localization string in storyboard with in application.
 I want to know to load localization storyboard in IOS with dynamically.
in generally, in order to load localization storyboard, we must change language setup in phone or not we have to use another localize string file.

But I want to load string of localization storyboard in my app.
Namely, I use two button in app.

One is **"English"**, another is **"French"**.
if user click "french" button, then app has to load French's storyboard's string.

Comment: Right now what are you doing while click on language button ? are you loading same `storyboard` or doing some conditional code ? can you show us your efforts on  this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSBundle.The storyboard is a file in the bundle.